# Error en xlsxWriter Python 3

Tags: python

Me da este error  "AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'"al correr el siguiente código en python. Estoy intentando crear un excel. He probado varios ejemplos y casos y siempre me da el mismo error. De hecho, ese código es copiado y pegado de la página oficial de la librería, luego no debería haber problemas.

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()
```

Muchas gracias,

Un saludo

Comment: ¿No tendrás algún módulo llamado `string.py` por casualidad en el directorio de trabajo de tu script principal (el que ejecutas con este ejemplo)?

Comment: Sí, es eso. Vaya error tonto. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, puede parecer tonto pero es bastante común, sobretodo si no se conoce la stdlib más o menos bien, es fácil que nombremos algún módulo propio con el mismo nombre que uno de la biblioteca estándar. Un saludo, por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so].